# Morphia @PrePersist not exactly getting called before save()

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a class in which I am modifying all string fields to replace the '.' character with "

```
class MyClass {
    String name;

    // Map of URL to Page Title
    HashMap<String, String> urlToTitle;

    @PrePersist
    void prePersist(){
       name = name.replace(".", "<DOT>");

       // Replace all . with <DOT> in nameSynonyms' keys and values in urlToTitle
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If I enter "firstname.lastname" for the 'name' field, it still throws an error saying that fields stored in db can't have "." in them. I thought since PrePersist methods are called before the save happens, the name field would get replaced. But that is not the case.

So my questions are:
1. How should I handle the replacement of the '.' character properly?
2. How can I write a method which does that conversion before save() is called?

Thanks

Comment: It is OK for the _value_ or a field to have a dot in it.  The _name_ of the field can't.  The above should not have created a field with a dot in it. Can you post the entire set of fields/annotations?

Comment: I just edited it to add another type of field. In my actual code there are about 30 fields - lists, hashmaps, hashmap of String to HashSet, etc. 

I understand the name of the fields can't have dots in them but the values can. One of the field is a map of URLs (key) to Page title (value). In that case I definitely need to remove the dots. There are other examples too. 

What do you suggest? thanks

Comment: Ah - OK that makes sense.  The only thing I can suggest is that you double check the logic.  For the maps make sure you remove the old key in addition to putting the new key/value.  Once you replace the dots it is a different entry.

Comment: The problem is also that the exception is thrown before @PrePersist mthod is called.